# Why do quoted objects stay quoted in lisp?

Tags: lisp, evaluation, quote

I have made a simple implementation of LISP using SICP metacircular evaluator as a reference, but even though I know and see the code I don't quite understand something about it. In the `apply` function that applies a closure to its arguments there is a piece of code that calls `eval` on each of it's arguments. If I quote an argument, then eval of that argument will give the raw form of that argument.

For clarity of the nature of the question and to present my current understanding of what is happening I will walk through an example.

```
(define f (lambda (x) (print x)))
(define g (lambda (x) (f x)))

; prints "bar" into the console
(g (quote bar))
```

First we call `g` with `(quote bar)` as the first parameter. The argument to `g` is evaluated to a symbol `bar`.

When `g` is evaluated, it passes it should **evaluate** it's argument and pass it to function `f`. But evaluating a symbol will cause a lookup from the environment, which doesn't seem to happen (if it did I should have printed an error, or something like that).

So what I want to know is why does the code print `bar` and not an error.

Comment: "When g is evaluated, it passes it should evaluate it's argument and pass it to function f" Well, no. When the *form* `(g (quote bar))` is evaluated, then the argument is evaluated (to the symbol `bar`), and this *value* is then passed to `f`, which then also passes it to `print` and so on. Evaluation and *bindings* are two different concepts, and you seem to be confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

I walked through the code with the debugger and now I believe I understand. When `g` was called, a new environment was created with `x` associated with the symbol `bar`. And when a function is executed it's **parameters** are being evaluated to the things that are stored in the environment. So it's not `bar` that got evaluated, it's `x` that got evaluated to `bar`. And after `x` is evaluated there's no second-time evaluation.

The reason why quoted things appear to stay quoted is because they actually do get unquoted, but they don't get evaluated as arguments (they only get evaluated once you explicitly call `eval` on them).

Comment: Things don't stay quoted. `(quote bar)` evaluates to the symbol `bar`. This symbol object is then what is passed around. Thus the symbol when passed isn't quoted, it's just passed as itself.

Comment: I shall edit my answer to clarify the logic